# How to avoid distributed transaction?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, oledb

There is a C# program calling a stored proc which has `insert linkedserver... from ....`. The C# program using Entity framework (`ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("....")`).

I've tried

1. Change the property "Enable Promotion of Distributed Transaction" to false.
2. Add "Enlist=false" in the connection string of the C# program
3. Change the MSDTC of the SQL server to allow anonymous authentication...

But it still gets the following error.

A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "...." returned message "No transaction is active.".